# How to get users email from MobileServiceClient?

Tags: android, azure, azure-active-directory

i am using:

```
private MobileServiceClient mClient;

    private void authenticate() {

        mClient.login("windowsazureactivedirectory", "Scheme", LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

I just can use getUserId()

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an authenticated GET request to `https://{your-appname}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` endpoint for retrieving more detailed information about the logged user. You could leverage [invokeApi](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.html#invokeApi-java.lang.String-) for retrieving the json data as follows:

[image]

You need to parse the response and retrieve user's email under `user_claims`.

Comment: Any concerns, feel free to let me know.